How to use .html files not .jsp in spring project?
I created a Spring project, connected the Tomcat server, added the necessary dependencies to pom.xml, and created the configuration files web.xml and applicationContextMVC.xml
created the necessary .html file at the location webapp/WEB-INF/views/.
When the server is started, the information is displayed from the index.jsp file from the webapp package, but I need to get it from my html file.

I tried to delete index.jsp
Moved the necessary html file to src/main/resources/static
nothing works


Try this:
src/main/resources/public/test.html
src/main/resources/resources/test.html - resources twice

Result location: http://some-host/test.html
